# Order a list of tuples

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I've got a List of tuples like this:

```
List<Tuple<Material, Material>> materials
```

Later on I'm iterating over it. However, **Item2** of the tuple **may** be **null**.

```
foreach(var material in materials)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

I'd like to order the Materials list so that the tuples with Item2 filled (not null at least) gets done first.

I'm assuming it's something like

```
foreach(var material in materials.OrderBy(*something*))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

However, I haven't really found out a way to do so..

Comment: " I'd like to order the Materials list so that the tuples with Item2 filled (not null at least) gets done first. "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order by and give value "0" if not null, "1" if null.

```
foreach(var material in materials.OrderBy(t=>t.Item2 == null ? 1 : 0))
```

This way the null ones will go at the end. First all "0" (not null) then all "1" (nulls)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the ones with `item2!=null` first, you could do this:

```
var materialslist = materials.Where(x => x.Item2 != null)
                             .Concat(materials.Where(x => x.Item2 == null)).ToList();
foreach(var material in materialslist)
{
     //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you, let me give that a try. 
I just tried materialen.OrderBy(f => f.Item2 != null).ThenBy(f => f.Item2 == null) but it seems like it doens't return any items if item2 is null

Comment: Paramone although my answer works, i think @OfirWinegarten's is more elegant.

Comment: Yeah, I do really like your answer aswell. You have my upvote!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var material in materials.OrderByDescending(s => s.Item2 != null));
```